# scanning the recieved sms in mobile and forwarding it automatically

Tags: java, mobile, sms, mobile-phones, mobile-application

I am trying to create an application which can automatically forward the sms recieved and send from the client mobile to another mobile number.

That is if i install the app in mobile A, that app should take what ever sms sent/recieved in mobile a to mobile b whose number i embed in that application.

Is this even possible?
If so how can i implement it for a java supported phone?
is there an exisitng program that can do this already for a java supported phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access SMS messages on any phone by using AT commands. Here is a link where you can find [some examples](http://www.developershome.com/sms/atCommandsIntro.asp).

If the mobile platform you are working with doesn't include the functions to access SMS messages from higher level you have to communicate with modem on your phone. By sending commands and reading answers on modem port you can manipulate with SMS messages so in case of your project you can simply periodically read SMS messages and sending them to another phone.

I am sure you can find some existing examples by browsing keywords "AT commands", "Java".